# Can i open svg syntax string into default android web browser as svg file on haxeflixel without server request/response manipulation?

Tags: android, svg, web, haxe, haxeflixel

Haxeflixel android targeting.
I need open text string with SVG syntax (XML) in default android browser, without server request/response actions. Something like just pushes text variable to the browser and display it as SVG file, like in the case when I do request and server response me SVG, but without internet and without creating the SVG file in the system storage (need additional permissions... in time of install apk...).

Is it possible?
Any help will be good.

Answer (score 0):

An actual browser window does not allow that, so I think what you want is a WebView.  It uses the default Android browser *engine* and is what you see in most apps.

Since you are using HaxeFlixel and it, in turn, is based on OpenFL, you can use its [`extension-webview`](https://github.com/HaxeExtension/extension-webview) native extension:

```
var htmlString = <...>;
extension.webview.WebView.openHtml(htmlString);
```

You can also specify a `onClose` callback.

Note: it might be necessary to wrap the SVG in some HTML.